# How to check if file exists and return HTTP 404 if not found

Tags: php, http

I have folder with files (index, register, login etc). I want to check if a file exists given a GET request. Example - localhost/?page=(page). I know how to make this, but i want to make 404 error page, if page not exist in folder.

If i have in folder pages file register.php and set `if($_GET['page'] = 'register') include('pages/register')`, if file not in folder, then return HTTP 404

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function file_exists() for that. Be sure to sanitize the input using basename()

```
$getpage = !empty($_GET['page']) ? basename($_GET['page']) : 'default.php';

if(!file_exists('pages/'.$getpage)){
    http_response_code(404);
    $getpage = '404.php';
}
include('pages/'.$getpage);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a server with apache or nginx you should set it up in their.
If you just testing out and you want to see how to get it done manually you can try and catch the require like so:

```
try{
  require('pages/' . $_GET["page"]);
}catch(Exception $e){
  require('pages/404.html');
}
```